# Excel Find and Replace

Tags: excel, replace

My question is how can I do a replace and find with a replace word that is never the same.
Basically, I would like to make a find and replace the word "x" for, let's say 5 rows with the word "A" and do a find and replace for the next five ones with the word "B" and so on for a thousand times. How do I manage to do that?

Comment: Is this about programming? C'on !

Answer (score 3):

Always make a backup of your data before you run code from the internet.  This will find all the instances of "x" in column A and replace them with the values you set in vaReplace.

```
Sub FindReplace()

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim vaReplace As Variant
    Dim lFound As Long
    Dim lRepCount As Long

    Const lMAX As Long = 5 'how many to replace before switching values
    Const sFIND As String = "x" 'what to look for
    Const lCOLUMN As Long = 1 'which column to look in

    'list of values to use as replacements
    vaReplace = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

    Set rFound = Sheet1.Columns(lCOLUMN).Find(sFIND, Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, lCOLUMN), xlValues, xlWhole)
    lFound = 1
    lRepCount = 0

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        Do
            If lFound > lMAX Then
                lRepCount = lRepCount + 1
                lFound = 1
            End If

            'if not enough in vaReplace, use the last value
            If lRepCount > UBound(vaReplace) Then lRepCount = UBound(vaReplace)

            rFound.Value = vaReplace(lRepCount)

            Set rFound = Sheet1.Columns(1).FindNext

            lFound = lFound + 1

        Loop Until rFound Is Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you export to CSV?  If so, you could do that and then use common command line tools in Linux or a text editor that you know has the features to find/replace as you have outlined.

You can use [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) or [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) to do this (on Linux, Windows).

Comment: I could definitely do that but I do not have any clue how to do that with Linux....

Comment: Install Gnumeric (lean, spreadsheet app) or LibreOffice (big office suite)